# Matching two or three words and optionals

Tags: regex

Im trying out some questions in an exam past paper, but i'm struggling on this one in particular. 
At the moment im thinking of something along the lines of:

```
([A-Z]*),? ([A-Z]*) ([A-Z]*)?
```

But this doesnt seem to be working, as I am certain I have the formatting/it being wrong in general. Help please?

In case your wondering the question is beloow so you have an idea of what i'm trying to achieve.
Many thanks.

> A personal name should contain one surname and one or more forenames. If the surname 
>   is placed before the forename(s), then the surname must be followed by a comma. Here 
>   are some examples:
>
> - GRAHAM ARTHUR CHAPMAN
> - ERIC IDLE
> - GILLIAM, TERRY
> - TERRY JONES
> - CLEESE, JOHN MARWOOD
> - MICHAEL PALIN
>
> How would you use the egrep command to find lines containing a personal name? You can 
>   assume that the names are written with capital letters only.

Comment: I think you want to find all lines with at least two words, and if there is a comma at all it should occur after the first word. At least that is how I interpret the question.

Comment: So you only need to find the lines, not extract the names into surname and array of forenames?

Comment: I think all which is needed is to find the lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[A-Z]+,?( [A-Z]+)+?$
```

What this does is make sure that the line starts with a letter optionally followed by a comma, and then any other group of words that are composed of a space followed by at least one letter.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex only allows two forenames. Use this (without capturing groups):

```
[A-Z]+,?( [A-Z]+)+
```

I've changed the `*`s to `+`s, as yours would match two spaces only as well.

Comment: This matches `TOM, DICK, AND HARRY` and also `123 NOT A NAME`

Comment: @Floris: Yes, because both lines *contain* a personal name as specified in the question. If you'd want to match lines that consist only of a name, you'd need to add start and end anchors (though I'm not sure how `egrep` handles them).

Comment: English is not my first language - apologies if I misinterpreted the question. I think "contains" can maybe mean both "has" and "has only"? With the examples given I thought it was the latter which is why I made my original comment - but I can see your point now. See answer from @Explosion Pills below using `^` and `$` anchors. I guess @Ted West has to tell us which is the right answer ( if he knows...)